# session.BeginTransaction() and transaction.Commit()

Tags: nhibernate, transactions, commit

I am new to Nhibernate, so my query may seem trivial to you.

We generally embed data operation code inside

```
  using (var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession())
  {
    using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
    {
       ...Code for CRUD operations
       transaction.Commit();
    }
  }
```

Because we generally BeginTransaction/Commit/Rollback for saving/updating/deleting data,

I wonder if `BeginTransaction()` and `Commit()` are required even if I am retriving data using
`session.Get<T>(id);` or
`session.CreateCriteria<T>().List();`

Please guide.

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you can't do data retrieval without transaction; all NH operations are transaction-centric.

Read this article by [Ayende Rahien](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2008/12/28/nh-prof-alerts-use-of-implicit-transactions-is-discouraged.aspx).

Comment: But doesn't he say that you should use transactions for every operation in NH? Why do you say "No"?

Comment: @HeavyWave: I meant "No, you can't do that without transaction", guess I read the line wrongly.

Answer (score 3):

You should always use transactions in queries. Not only for the performance but also for concurrency reasons, and [Ayende](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2008/12/28/nh-prof-alerts-use-of-implicit-transactions-is-discouraged.aspx) says about it.

His Hibernate profiler shows and alert if you use queries not in transaction scope.